# Is it always possible to order a multi-dimensional array in all dimensions? How?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

Suppose, I have an `n`-dimensional array of integers (for `n=1` it's a vector, for `n=2` it's a rectangular matrix, for `n=3` it's a parallelepiped, etc). I need to reorder elements of the array so that elements in each row, column, etc are in a non-decreasing order.

- Is it possible for any input array?
- <s>Is the required ordering unique for any input array?</s> I just realized that the answer for this question in general is **no**, e.g. for square matrices.
- Is the required ordering unique for any input array that has different lengths in all dimensions?
- What is the fastest algorithm to produce the required ordering?

Comment: Could you define "reorder" more precisely?

Comment: So, for a 2D array of integers, you would want the largest integer in the bottom right corner? It seems to me that sorting each column, and then each row will give you such a reordering. I'm sure there's a faster way to do it though.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei "reorder" means "rearrange", "put the same elements is a (possibly) different order". In other words, the resulting array must contain the same integers, with the same multiplicity (in case an integer appears multiple times at different positions in the input array), but possibly at different positions (none, one, some or all of an element's indices may change).

Comment: @AlptiginJalayr Yes, the largest integer (or, if there are several copies of the largest integer, one of them) must be in the bottom right corner of a matrix (or, for general multi-dimensional arrays, in the position where all indices have their max possible values).

Comment: @ZiyaoWei I wonder, what ambiguity do you see in the word "reorder"?

Comment: @PiotrShatalin Not really, but the sorting solution seems rather trivial to be the right answer, so I think "reorder" might need a clearer definition. Turns out to be not the case, of course.

Comment: @PiotrShatalin, I guess he was looking for if there are any constraints on the reorder operation.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for any input array?

Yes, if we will look on the array as a single dimension array, with the same number of elements, and then sort it, by traversing it back to the original n-dimensions array, it remains sorted, since for each `i1,....,i_k,...,i_m`: for all `i_k < i_k'`:

```
i_1 + n1*i_2 + n2^2*i_3 + .... (n_k-1)^(k-1)(i_k) + ... < i_1 + n1*i_2 + n2^2*i_3 + .... (n_k-1)^(k-1)(i_k') + ...
Thus (the array is ordered):
arr[i_1 + n1*i_2 + n2^2*i_3 + .... (n_k-1)^(k-1)(i_k) + ...] < arr[ i_1 + n1*i_2 + n2^2*i_3 + .... (n_k-1)^(k-1)(i_k') + ...]
Thus (back to original array):
arr[i_1][i_2]...[i_k]... < arr[i_1][i_2]...[i_k']...
```

As for the 2nd question:

> Is the required ordering unique for any input array that has different
>   lengths in all dimensions?

No:

```
1 1          1 3
3 4          1 4
5 6          5 6
```

> What is the fastest algorithm to produce the required ordering?

One solution is suggested already: regard it is a big long array and sort it.
Complexity is `O(n_1*n_2*...*n_m*log(n_1*n_2*...*n_m))`

My gut says if you could do it faster, you could sory faster then `O(nlogn)`, but I have no proof for this claim, so it might be wrong.

Comment: I think a full sorting is not necessary.

Comment: @lcn It could be redundant, my gut says it is not - but I am not sure about it at all. Anyway, the point of the answer is showing it can be done algorithmically for all input cases, I'd love to see more optimized algorithms as well, if such exist.

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate more about Alptigin Jalayr's idea.

Suppose we have rows sorted, so for the following data, we have `a <= b` and `c <= d`.

```
     .       .
..., a, ..., b, ...
     .       .
..., c, ..., d, ...
     .       .
```

When `a` is greater than `c`, i.e. `c <a`, then swap of them gives us `c < b` since `a <= b`, and `a <=d` since `b <= d` (if `b > d`, we swap `b` and `d` as well). In a word, sorting rows first and then columns next can give you the desired matrix.